# My Laravel Export Excel Function is not working

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel

my controller code

```
  public function test( Request $request ){
    $type = intval($request->type);
    return (new CustomerEx)->forType($type)->download('invoices.xlsx');
  }
```

and export code

```
  private $type;

  public function forType($type)
  {
    $this->type = $type;
    return $this;
  }
```

this return null
help me..

Comment: Welcome to SO, your code returns null also for me, you should add some details. Please read here on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you do `dd($type)` after the `$type = intval($request->type);` line, and tell me what the output is?

Comment: How did you fix it? Share your answer, so others can make a use of it, if they have the same problem. @Hossein